# Why fragment onCreateView being called twice?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm using viewpager but have problem with fragment.
My fragment onCreateView being called twice.
Here is my code
Adapter:

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

/**
 * @param fm
 *            Fragment manager
 */
public QuestionAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if (position == 4) {

        return InfoFragment.getInstance();
    }

    return QuestionFragment.getInstance(position);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 5;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getItemPosition(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

My fragment code:

```
public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment {

private int mPos;

@Bind(R.id.fragment_question_group_layout)
RadioGroup questionGroup;

public static QuestionFragment getInstance(int pos) {

    QuestionFragment fragment = new QuestionFragment();
    fragment.setPos(pos);
    return fragment;
}

public void setPos(int pos) {
    this.mPos = pos;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LogUtil.e("QuestionFragment", "Pos : " + mPos);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    switch (mPos) {

        case 0 :

            displayQuestion(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question1_content));
            break;
        case 1 :

            displayQuestion(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question2_content));
            break;
        case 2 :

            displayQuestion(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question3_content));
            break;
        default :

            displayQuestion(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question4_content));
            break;
    }

    return view;
}
```

And here is log:

- E/QuestionFragment﹕ Pos : 0
- E/QuestionFragment﹕ Pos : 1
- E/QuestionFragment﹕ Pos : 2
- E/QuestionFragment﹕ Pos : 3
- E/InfoFragment﹕ Pos :
- E/QuestionFragment﹕ Pos : 0
- E/QuestionFragment﹕ Pos : 0
- E/QuestionFragment﹕ Pos : 0
- E/QuestionFragment﹕ Pos : 0
- E/InfoFragment﹕ Pos :

Edit:
I already set: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); on activity
And above logs got when I open activity, no swipe action. Just open activity and get logs

Comment: I don't see the problem. `onCreateView()` is called whenever the fragment is (re-created).  `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is intended to create and destroy fragments on the fly. It also --by default-- keeps only the current as well as the neighboring (left/right) fragments. So it is normal to have a fragment re-created as you flip through pages.

Comment: Problem is I already set viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
And why in 2nd call, my pos = 0?
Debugged and on getItem of adapter, my fragment just called 1 time
Also above log is logged when I open activity - do not swipe pager

Comment: Why are you returning POSITION_NONE instead of POSITION_UNCHANGED in getItemPosition()?

Comment: @JacobRas: I tried both but nothing changed :(

Comment: Well, if you have no specific reason to use NONE I would keep it to the default UNCHANGED. Looking at the log outputs you posted, do they appear in that exact order (first 0,1,2,3 and then 0,0,0,0)? Also: when do you get those log outputs? Please describe what you are doing on the device, how you are swiping et cetera.

Comment: @JacobRas: All fragments display same layout(layout of first fragment) :(
I just open activity and get above logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem and it is:

- My phone's orientation is : portrait
- My application's is : landscape

When I run my app, then fragment will recreate due to on configuration change. I putted

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

on manifest then everything work